# Insufficient tokens for quota

Tags: google-api, rate-limiting

i'm accessing the Google Mobile Friendly Test API via curl

And i frequently get the response

> "Insufficient tokens for quota 'RegularGroup' and limit 'ProjectQps'
>   of service 'searchconsole.googleapis.com' for consumer
>   'api_key:MYAPIKEY"

I do a request every 10 seconds or more, so i do not hammer the api with too many requests.

I have no idea, why google answers like this :(

Cheers and thanks in advance

Adrian